# Visio: Cannot find shape in a group shape

Tags: c#, vba, visio

I am transfering vba code over to c# using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio library. I am having a hard time figuring out why I'm getting an "Object name not found" exception. Code below:

```
foreach (IVisio.Shape t in GroupStall.Shapes)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(t.Name);
                    }
                    var aa = "door" + index;
                    IVisio.Shape test = GroupStall.Shapes.ItemU[aa];
```

I'm using the for each loop for debugging purposes. In the output of foreach is:

```
headrail2
headrail1
toilet1
toprail1
siderail1A
door1
stallwidth1
```

I already know that "door1" exist in there so I shouldn't need to always go through a foreach loop just to assign it to a shape object. But when I get to assigning "door1" shape to "test, I get the exception, "Object name not found." Any help on why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already found the answer to my own question. In C# if you want to assign a shape object using a shape's name you use:

```
IVisio.Shape test = GroupStall.Shapes["name"]
```

I found this weird because I could not do this in VBA, VBA you had to use the item method to find a shape by name:

```
test = GroupStall.Shapes.Item("name")
```

Hope this helps anyone else developing in visio using C#.

Comment: And what member do you think your C# indexer is invoking? That's right, some `get_Item` method. Also if `Shapes` is a collection class, by convention its `Item` property should be its *default member*, meaning `Set test = GroupStall.Shapes("name")` should work. Note the `Set` keyword required in VBA to assign any object reference.